# Realm instance in background thread

Tags: java, realm

We have long lived [issue](https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/issues/323) that we were not able to reproduce on our devices.

Luckily, one of our users was able to reproduce, more, he is a developer and contributed [fix](https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/pull/324).

However, the fix is not obvious for me, why changing the method from static to class method fixes the issue. From java perspective we just adding one hidden parameter this and nothing else.

Can someone comment what might be wrong with our [`ReadinToCVS`](https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/blob/a1d7e9978c332d2070db3ab5a7fef9de66933740/app/src/main/java/org/glucosio/android/tools/ReadingToCSV.java) or [`ExportPresenter`](https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/blob/a1d7e9978c332d2070db3ab5a7fef9de66933740/app/src/main/java/org/glucosio/android/presenter/ExportPresenter.java)? And why proposed fix is solving it?

Comment: `GlucoseReading reading = readings.get(i);` returning `null` indicate that the list is created by you. ReamLists/Results cannot contain `null` values. Since that list is just an argument to your function, it is impossible to tell why that might be happening.

Comment: Thanks for giving some clue!